# Combination of grouping by several fields and select latest date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table of responses to a survey (assessments) an area can submit several assessments but I only want the responses for the latest assessment per area.

Below is my data, the records marked with * would be the ones I would like return

```
AsessmentID AssessmentDate Status  AreaID Response Category
          1    01/01/2016  Complete    1       1    A
          1    01/01/2016  Complete    1       2    B
          1    01/01/2016  Complete    1       4    C
          2    05/01/2016  Complete    1       5*   A
          2    05/01/2016  Complete    1       4*   B
          2    05/01/2016  Complete    1       5*   C
          3    02/01/2016  Complete    2       1*   A
          3    02/01/2016  Complete    2       2*   B
          3    02/01/2016  Complete    2       4*   C
          4    03/01/2016  Complete    3       5*   A
          4    03/01/2016  Complete    3       4*   B
          4    03/01/2016  Complete    3       5*   C
          5    04/01/2016  Draft       3       3    A
          5    04/01/2016  Draft       3       2    B
          5    04/01/2016  Draft       3       3    C
```

Here is my linq so far but it only returns 2 responses

```
from c in db.Answers.Where(b => b.Status == Status.Complete)
                                  group c by new { c.AreaID, c.AssessmentID, c.AssessmentDate} into grp
                                  select grp.OrderByDescending(c => c.AssessmentDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var results = db.Answers
    .Where(x => x.Status == Status.Complete)
    .GroupBy(x => x.AreaID)     //group by AreaID
    .Select(x => new            //project onto anonymous type with the data we need
    {
        //the AreaID
        AreaID = x.Key,         

        //get a collection for the responses we need
        Responses = x           
            //Group by the date of the assessment
            .GroupBy(r => r.AssessmentDate)

            //order descending so we get the last responses
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.Key)

            //take only the first in the list (latest)
            .Take(1)

            //project the ordered result extracting the properties we want to show
            .SelectMany(r => r.Select(ri => new { ri.AssessmentDate, ri.Response}))
    })
    //enumerate 
    .ToList();
```

Using this code to print to console:

```
foreach (var g in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("AreaID: {0}", g.AreaID);
    Console.WriteLine("Date      Response");
    foreach (var r in g.Responses)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", r.AssessmentDate.ToShortDateString().PadRight(10,' '), r.Response);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You should get this:

```
AreaID: 1
Date      Response
5/1/2016   5
5/1/2016   4
5/1/2016   5

AreaID: 2
Date      Response
2/1/2016   1
2/1/2016   2
2/1/2016   4

AreaID: 3
Date      Response
3/1/2016   5
3/1/2016   4
3/1/2016   5
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant, the only trouble is, I failed to mention that each response also has a property called 'category' and I need an average category value for each area

Comment: I think you need to define how you'll calculate the average on A, B, C.. values first. Then it should not be so hard to figure it out what you want. :)

Comment: count(Category) / sum(Category)

Comment: Ideally I need the responses to be a flat list rather than nested by Area